# What does this headline mean?

Tags: translation

女子700万买下学位房学区调整致算盘落空.  I looked the words up individually using MDBG and also used Google Translate to get a general idea, but it still didn't make any sense.

Comment: What did you get? Which part make no sense ?

Comment: "算盘落空" is an idiom, meaning "the plan fails". The sentence could be read as `女子 spends 700万 to buy 学位房, but due to 学区调整, her 算盘落空`. So, "a lady spent 7,000,000 to buy a school-district house, but due to the adjustment of the school district, her plan failed".

Comment: BTW, 学位房 would be 学区房 in a general description. "学位" here definitely doesn't mean an academic degree, but rather a "position for study". The background information is the school district policy in China. Generally children can only study in the primary/middle schools within the school district they live, or, money and guanxi are required if you want to choose a school outside your school district.

Comment: @Stan I think we have an answer...

Comment: @user3306356 maybe next time :) I'm struggling with my work

Answer (score 2):

"Woman's plan to buy 7 million-dollar-house in a school district fails"

Comment: You didn't explain why fails...

Answer (score 2):

There is a concept which may be unfamiliar for you non-Chinese. 学区 is the area which covers a part of residential areas and the school which have responsibility to it have to receive the students in it unconditionally. 学位房 means a house in a 学区.

If you have properties in a 学区, your kids are allowed to join a school without exams and complicated procedures. Since everyone wants his kid to join a better school, wealthier guys tries to buy a house in the 学区 which a better school is responsible for it.

Thus, the price of houses in these better area are always high. So it cost her 700万(=7 million Chinese Yuan). But the area of that 学区 was adjusted by government, so her kids are not allowed to join the better school. That's why 她的算盘落空了(her plan has failed). And that's the interest point of this news.

Answer (score 0):

女子700万买下学位房学区调整致算盘落空

有一个女子，花了700万，买下了一个学位房。后来学区进行了调整，导致她的算盘落空了。

A women bought a house with 7 million yuan. That house was in a good school district then. But late on, recently, the school district adjusted, and this house  changed to another school district. Her calculation is no longer valid.